# ReactiveCocoa: is there a way to have something happen after all subscribers receive completed/error

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I have a signal where I expect that I will get a complete or error on, and there are other subscribers.

I want to subscribe to completed/error, but be the last one to act (after all other subscribers get a chance).  I was hoping that finally would do that, but it seems that it does not.

Comment: It's hard to answer without more detail. I could ask a bunch of questions, but it would be more effective if you provided some sample code.

Comment: There exists a signal that has unknown subscribers that update an object on complete (I cannot change that). I want to add another subscriber that saves that object somewhere on complete -- this new subscriber must execute after all of the others.

Comment: @LouFranco Using the signal's subscribers to track that state seems like a bad coupling -- that should remain private, and you should track that elsewhere. If you're in a position to know that the other signals exist you should be able to enqueue them somewhere -- otherwise how can you guarantee that those are the only subscriptions? Or that they exist in the first place -- a year from now that could change and break the implicitly dependent saving code.

Comment: @IanHenry I basically came to that conclusion myself. I'd like something like doComplete, but a block called after the completes are sent, not before.  I don't really want to subscribe at all, but I want to do something when the signal is complete and complete listeners are done.

Comment: @LouFranco semi-related but not really: be careful with `doCompleted`. It's not totally intuitive if you're new to RAC. It'll fire once *for each subscriber*... which makes sense when you realize that a signal doesn't inherently have these events, but there's a (signal x subscriber) product that's the actual event carrier. But still. It's very... unexpected. (This is why Trello uses the `subscribeFinally` helper instead of `finally` for `FCTClient` requests)